# Cannot find Highlight tool in Adobe Reader or Okular

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, okular, annotation

I use Elementary OS Luna 64 bit. I'm trying to get the PDF annotating tools for highlighting text on PDF documents. I tried Adobe Reader and Okular. But both haven't that feature on my PC. But when I gogling I could see that both of those readers have that annotating feature. So what is the reason for that. Is that a missing of  plug in or something?

Answer (score 59):

In Okular, you should press <kbd>F6</kbd>. then you will see a toolbar with different options for highlighting.

In old version it would appear like the following

[image]

In newer versions it will show as the following (screenshot from version 21.08.3):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to help clarify?

Comment: @Seth to highlight where the F6 key is?

Comment: @Oli No, of the toolbar.

Comment: Nothing happens if I press F6. Okular 0.21.3 on Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: this solved my problem: [Okular doesn't allow me to do reviews on certain pdfs](http://superuser.com/a/676733/126352)

Comment: In my version of Okular. Go to the tab Tools and then click on Review